How can software developers ensure the security of their softwares, so that consumers don't mess with it?
The question is as it is.
As a software developer, how can you ensure that when consumers/customers/users download your softwares, they cannot edit it to create a different version of it ?
Some ways can include: 1. encrypt the source code (decrypts when you run it)
2. obfuscate it
3. rely on getting license/copy rights.
Anyone know of any other way ? Since these approaches seem pretty immediate.

Obfuscation is, in some mathematical sense, impossible. So this is fundamentally an economic issue: you raise the cost of editing it so high that it's no longer worth it.

You can't.  You can make it harder or more expensive for someone to do that, but you can't prevent it.  None of those ways you mention prevents that.
See, e.g., https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/2001/0515.html#3.

Download an application from the App Store onto your iPhone. If the app is not identical to the one uploaded by the developer then there is a cryptographic step that will stop it from running. If the user goes around the App Store, no such guarantee.
So for that the developer needs to keep their software safe. You won’t be able to run a modified version of it. But you could run some independently created software that somehow resembles the original. This has happened, with two applications having the same name except for one letter, and people running the “wrong” software.

Hi gnahser, thank you so much for your comment, this is very interesting.
